# Does Element.getAttribute() work in IE7 with unknown-to-IE attributes?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-7, custom-attributes

I'm trying to add [event rich snippets](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164506) to my site so that Google can know about the events. Then, leading to the cause of my question, I want to use the time data to do some various Javascript operations. I am using the microdata approach Google outlines in the first link, but I am using `span` elements instead of `time` ones, since IE 7 (and 8) will treat the unknown `time` element as an inline element and I'd rather not use the [HTML5 shiv](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) if not absolutely necessary.

I am able to retrieve all the appropriate time `span`s (using `jQuery("span[itemprop=startDate]")`). However, in IE7 (and not in IE8 or FF or the WebKit-based browsers) I cannot get the 'datetime' attribute that I know each `span` has. It doesn't matter whether I use the native `getAttribute()` method or jQuery's `attr()`, I always get `null` back.

Any idea why and how I can work around this? Thanks!

**Update:** I have added a [simple example](http://labs.bubblefoundry.com/attributes/). In Chrome I get alert that say 'datetime via DOM methods is: 2010-11-25' and 'datetime jQuery is: 2010-11-25' but in IE7 I get 'datetime via DOM methods is: null' and 'datetime via jQuery is: undefined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does, at least for `div` and `b` elements. Oddly it doesn't seem to with a `span`. So, try using `div` instead.

Comment: That's strange, because `div` is a block element while `b` is an inline one like `span`...